# Generators of relative $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathscr B)$ be a measurable space. For some $Y\subseteq X$, $Y\in\mathscr B$ and define
$$\mathscr B_Y\equiv\{Y\cap B\,|\,B\in\mathscr B\}$$
to be the “relative $\sigma$-algebra” on $Y$ induced by $\mathscr B$. It is not difficult to check that $\mathscr B_Y$ is a legit $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

Suppose that $\mathscr G\subseteq\mathscr B$ generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr B$. If one defines
$$\mathscr G_Y\equiv\{Y\cap G\,|\,G\in\mathscr G\},$$
is it true that the “relative generator set” $\mathscr G_Y$ generates the relative $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr B_Y$ on $Y$?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83077/a-question-about-sigma-algebras-and-generators?rq=1).

It's true. Let $\sigma_Y(\mathscr G_Y)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr G_Y$ on $Y$. Since $\mathscr G_Y\subseteq\mathscr B_Y$, it is clear that $\sigma_Y(\mathscr G_Y)\subseteq\mathscr B_Y$. As for the other direction, let
$$\mathscr H\equiv\{B\subseteq X\,|\,Y\cap B\in\sigma_Y(\mathscr G_Y)\}.$$
Clearly, $\mathscr G\subseteq\mathscr H$ and it is easy to see that $\mathscr H$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Hence, $\mathscr B\subseteq \mathscr H$. This readily implies that $\mathscr B_Y\subseteq\sigma_Y(\mathscr G_Y)$.